# creating a custom header in windows phone browser

Tags: browser, header, windows-phone, custom-headers

Hey I want to create a custom header in windows phone that is send when I use the `webbrowser1.navigate` according to msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491275.aspx the function has an *additionalHeaders* argument but I cant get it to work in my app and keep getting a error saying that the webbrowser.navigate don't take 4 arguments. Hope there is something simple I'm doing wrong, or there is another way to add custom headers to the phone:WeBrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Navigate` version, the one you linked is WPF-specific. Use this signature instead [`WebBrowser.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).